# Making Image as Plane slightly transparent

Tags: python

Is there a code in python perhaps, to make an image imported as plane slightly transparent. I have seen tutorials how to make the background of a PNG image transparent, but that's not what I am after. It is easily done if you drag and drop the image as an empty, however I need the image to be a plane, because sections of it need to be cut out. The actual image, not the background, needs to be semi-transparent.
Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thank you in advance. Oh, and the photo itself is an image of someones face. I guess we need to make the image texture transparent?

Comment: Add a transparent shader and connect the shader of the image plane to a mix shader node. Then altering the values for the mix shader's fac you can make the plane semi-transparent. As an alternative, if the image plane is using a principled shader, then just adjust the values for "alpha"

Comment: Got you.. in Eevee it works, Can one get this to work in workbench mode?